# Oracle SQL Error: ORA-0923 FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I run the following code through the command console and get the following error

> ORA-0923 FROM keyword not found where expected.

I'm also using 11g.

```
SELECT c.customer# "C#", o.order# "ORDER#",
       o.orderdate "ORDER DATE",
       NVL2(o.shipdate, 'Not shipped', 'shipped'),
       o.shipdate "Ship date",
       o.shipdate-o.orderdate AS "lead time in days",
TRUNC((o.shipdate-o.orderdate)/30), 2) AS "lead time in months"
FROM customers c, orders o
ORDER BY "lead time in days" DESC, c.customer# ASC, o.order# ASC;
```

Comment: Your `TRUNC(statement), 2)` make error here

Comment: There is one extra ) in your TRuNK function

Comment: If you're programming you should use a proper editing tool. Such an editor would have shown you matched and unmatched brackets, which would have allowed you to find your typo immediately. There are many free ones on the net, [Notepad++ is very popular on Windows](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). IDEs like [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) do this too.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you are missing a join condition between `customers` and `orders` which will result in a cross join between those tables. This is hardly what you intended and is a result of using (or trying to use) the old, ancient and outdated implicit joins in the `where` clause (which you forgot). You should learn how to use the "modern" (25 years old) and more robust explicit `JOIN` operator instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove extra bracket in Trunc and run the below query:

```
SELECT c.customer# "C#", o.order# "ORDER#",
o.orderdate "ORDER DATE",
NVL2(o.shipdate, 'Not shipped', 'shipped'),
o.shipdate "Ship date",
o.shipdate-o.orderdate  "lead time in days",
TRUNC((o.shipdate-o.orderdate)/30,2) "lead time in months"
FROM customers c, orders o
ORDER BY "lead time in days" DESC, c.customer# ASC, o.order# ASC;
```